# Image gallery column not aligning properly (Twitter-Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image-gallery

I have a pretty simple task to do, but I can't figure out why it is not working... My goal is to have a series of images with captions with various grid configuration across sm, md and lg. However, the alignment is always messed up. It is a little hard to explain, but really easy to demonstrate. So here is the demo: http://www.bootply.com/zrEgRHnaup

As you can see when changing the window size, the grid is pretty messed up. Playing with the code on bootply, I realized that the problem is not occurring when all the images are of the same size. How can I make this grid work even with uneven image sizes?

```
<section id="detail" class="greenBG">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                <div class="about-text">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h4>Confection</h4>
                        <h2><strong>Vivamus</strong></h2>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>Fusce in pulvinar nisi. Cras tristique sed orci.<br><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Curabitur</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x280" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Aenean tempor erat ut consequat rutrum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Cras</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x250" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Point d'amure de voile enrouleur avec renfort radial, oeil ou sangle au besoin.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Génois Drisse</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x250" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Nulla auctor vel arcu eu egestas. Vestibulum ut sapien finibus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Amure</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/250x300" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Aenean tempor erat ut consequat rutrum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Driss</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x250" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p> Integer at velit nec lectus facilisis varius sed non ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Curabitur</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x250" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Fusce nec pretium dolor. Sed commodo ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Latte</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x270" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Nulla auctor vel arcu eu egestas. Vestibulum ut sapien finibus.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Risonite</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x220" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Vivamus sed orci tristique, pulvinar odio at, congue urna.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Voyilur</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x250" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquents.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <h5 class="text-center">Tristique</h5>
                <img src="https://placehold.it/200x250" class="center-block img-responsive">
                <p>Suspendisse diam diam, finibus ac urna id, hendrerit tempus nibh. Nulla eget consequat nibh.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add the code from the ply to your question.  If the ply gets deleted (or the service is not working, even temporarily) the question is incomplete (and impossible to answer).  Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: If you cannot make all the image the same size (or do not want to) - perhaps you should be looking at masonry plugin for layouts (http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/images.html).  A simple grid for gallery assumes all your thumbnails are to be the same size (for the grid)

Comment: I noticed that when I take all images of the same size (200x250), I still get some misalignment when I have a sm window size. So the problem is not only with the images not all being of the same size :O

Comment: Hmmm, but is the text (description) the same size for all images?  How about using bootstrap's own thumbnails? (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails)

Comment: I tried using bootstrap's thumbnails system with caption, but it's still not working: http://www.bootply.com/PMH1ggVkIO